# Intermittent connection failures with Arduino WiFiClientSecure on ESP8266

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I'm seeing intermittent connection failures connecting to a host on port 433 with `WiFiClientSecure` (ESP8266 Arduino-core). The debug log below shows that the handshake stops after receiving the server hello. I don't know how to decipher the more detailed information in the trace.

The last information in the trace is a `Alert: close notify`.

The client is currently configured to *not* verify the server authenticity either by certificate fingerprint or certificate chain. AFAIU it doesn't even get to the stage where it *could* attempt to do so. Hence, that doesn't seem to be relevant anyhow.

Version: ESP8266 Arduino-core 2.4.2

**Sketch snippet**

```
WiFiClientSecure client;
Serial.printf("Connecting to: %s:%d\n", HOST.c_str(), PORT);
if (client.connect(HOST, PORT)) {
  client.println("GET " + path + " HTTP/1.1");
  // and so on
} else {
  Serial.println("Connection failed");
}
```

**Debut output**

```
Connecting to: thingpulse.com:443
[hostByName] request IP for: thingpulse.com
[hostByName] Host: thingpulse.com IP: 217.26.52.113
:ref 1
:ref 2
State:  sending Client Hello (1)
:wr 95 95 0
:wrc 95 95 0
:sent 95
:rn 536
:rch 536, 536
:rch 1072, 536
:rch 1608, 536
:rd 5, 2144, 0
:rdi 536, 5
:rd 80, 2144, 5
:rdi 531, 80
State:  receiving Server Hello (2)
:rd 5, 2144, 85
:rdi 451, 5
:rd 2054, 2144, 90
:rdi 446, 446
:c 446, 536, 2144
:rdi 536, 536
:c 536, 536, 1608
:rdi 536, 536
:c 536, 536, 1072
:rdi 536, 536
:c0:rch 536, 536
 536, 536
:rn 152
:rd 152, 152, 0
:rdi 152, 152
:c0 152, 152
pm open,type:2 0
:ur 2
Alert: close notify
Connection failed
```

Comment: I'd recommend asking over at arduino.stackexchange.com

Comment: The WifiClientSecure  has changed the TLS implementation. The new implementation which bases on "BearSSL" does not accept all certificates by default, therefore the connection will fail. You have to white list the server certificate or it's key or disable certificate checking via ` client.setInsecure();`.